# Inherited by implicit conversion orderingToOrdered from Ordered[A] to Ordered[Ordered[A]]?

Tags: scala

This comes up in the scala api for [Ordered](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.math.Ordered) when you click on 'By inheritance' in Ordering section.  The [Ordered page on GitHub](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/math/Ordered.scala#L1) shows an implicit conversion from Ordering to Ordered called orderingToOrdered, but what does "Ordered[A] to Ordered[Ordered[A]]" mean?  The Ordered[Ordered[A]] part is confusing because it appears like it's the same thing twice.

*Just learning Scala so the terms I use might not be correct.

Comment: @m-z I think (s)he meant this: http://i.imgur.com/6MoomAD.png It looks like a Scaladoc bug.

Comment: Ah.. I guess I was looking for a method in the table as opposed to something behind a weird green background. Yeah, that doesn't look right.

Comment: I guess the problem is here: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.6/src/scaladoc/scala/tools/nsc/doc/html/page/Template.scala#L249 I have not found yet a scaladoc issue in the JIRA bug tracker.

Comment: Just  a bug, eh?  Lol.  Ok, thanks.